# Freezing feelings towards Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

This code freezes VS2010 sp1:

```
// STC_14_1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

void my_new_handler()
{
    cerr << "Mem. alloc failed.";
    std::exit(-1);
}
//std::unexpected_handler std::set_unexpected(std::unexpected_handler);

class STC
{
    std::new_handler old;
public:
    STC(std::new_handler n_h):old(std::set_new_handler(n_h))
    {   }

    ~STC()
    {
        std::set_unexpected(old);
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    STC stc(&my_new_handler);
    while (true)
    {
        auto tmp = new int[50000];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it that I'm doing something wrong or it's VS's problem?

Comment: Do you really mean `std::set_unexpected` in `STC::~STC`? It seems strange to replace the default `unexpected_handler` with the default `new_handler`.

Comment: @Charles no of course not. My mistake.

Comment: What options are you giving the compiler when you compile this?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is endless:

```
   while (true)
    {
        auto tmp = new int[50000];
    }
```

You have to define a condition to exit outside of the loop. In counterpart, VS will be frozen iterating through the loop and draining memory from the heap (since you allocate a new block of memory in every iteration).

EDIT: Your handler is not called  because it has to be defined as `void __cdecl`:

```
void __cdecl  no_memory () {
  cout << "Failed to allocate memory!\n";
  exit (1);
}
```

Since handler is not called, the problem is in endless loop.
It works on my VS 2010.

Comment: @Vladimir but did you've realize that new_handler is set before entering this loop? P.S. What a individual could upvote your question ;) ?

Comment: -1: The loop is meant to allocate all available process memory so the exception handler is called.

Comment: @Sebastian and @There is nothing we can do - the problem is in the loop since handler IS NOT CALLED. Without the loop - VS will not be frozen. As simple as that. But, anyway edited my post and proposed a solution that working on my computer (even with endless loop). P.S. It seems that however there is something we can do :)

Comment: @Vladimir but the whole point of having this handler is that it will be called implicitly. My code works as intended in gcc so I think it's ok.

Comment: __cdecl is the default, you don't need to specify it, and the compiler will throw a type error if the calling convention is wrong.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do - handler is called now (on my computer). So, VS is not frozen. You can read more following next link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fath9te.aspx  So, there is something we can do :)

Comment: At the end: VS is frozen because of endless loop. As simple as that. We can try to allocate a big memory block without a loop and discuss why handler is not (if it is not) called, but VS definitely wouldn't be frozen.

Comment: @Vladimir so why gcc is not frozen and behaved as expected?

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'freezes', are you sure that it's not just that the code is still actually running and has not hit the new handler code yet. I tried running the example `set_new_handler` code from the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fath9te%28v=vs.80%29), and it still took a minute or so and the example is allocating 5000000 at a time rather than 50000.

Comment: I was actually running a debug version. My mistake :-)